# ImageButton wont display image when using srcCompat

Tags: java, android, xml

My Problem is this, There's two buttons that display local images, but it doesnt render, any ideas on what to do here ??

[image: Screen Shot]

XML File for items in the list View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfi_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nfi_name"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfi_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nfi_name"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/nfi_btnLike"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nfi_flags"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nfi_btnFlag"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_rock_on" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/nfi_btnFlag"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-17dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nfi_status"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_stop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfi_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfi_likes"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nfi_btnLike"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nfi_btnLike" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nfi_flags"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nfi_btnFlag"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nfi_btnFlag" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The images used are open source PNG EMotee images,Web doesnt have accurate info on this problem

Comment: Does linked `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: use `android:src="@mipmap/ic_rock_on"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_rock_on"`

Comment: @GaëtanMaisse Yes it does

Comment: i had a feel he was using weird tags @tahsinRupam

Comment: In your code, use `imgButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_rock_on)`

Comment: @tahsinRupam Sweet it worked, Thanks man

Comment: also this vector drawing limits the app to lollipop and above?? so is useless app >.>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`app:srcCompat` is defined in [AppCompat library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7) so you have to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton` instead of `ImageButton`.

If you don't need features available in AppCompat lib then keep your `ImageButton` and use `android:src` attribute (`setImageResource` method is the Java version of this).

---

As pointed out by @Ferdous Ahamed, these icons should be in a `drawable` folder instead of `mipmap` one, the latter is only used for app launcher icon.

Comment: If you use AndroidX make sure to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton`

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `app:src="YOUR_DRAWABLE"` instead of `app:srcCompat="YOUR_DRAWABLE"`.

**FYI,** Always put image resources in `drawable` folder instead of `mipmap`. `mipmap` is only for launcher icons.